# Ag-grid react cell skeleton loaders

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, grid, ag-grid

I am trying to add a skeleton loader to ag grid in my react application that looks like this however I'm not sure it is possible?

[image]

I have tried using overlayTemplate and also loadingCellRenderer but I can't seem to get it to work. Has anyone done anything like this before?

Answer (score 1):

You can customize the loadingCellRenderer if you are using server side rendering (`rowModelType: "serverSide"`). Combine the use of `gridOptions.columnApi.getColumnState()` provided in params, you can  have the width of each grey oval match the width of each column.

```js
class CustomLoadingCellRenderer {
    init(params) {
        let eGui = document.createElement('div');
        eGui.style.height = "100%";
        eGui.style.width = "100%";

        /* You might want to change the hard coded padding  */
        /* or border-radius depends on your need.           */
        for(let column of params.columnApi.getColumnState()){
            if(column.hide){
                continue;
            }
            let cell = document.createElement('div');
            cell.style.display = "inline-block";
            cell.style.width = column.width + 'px';
            cell.style.height = "100%";
            cell.style.padding = '15px';
            let oval = document.createElement('div');
            oval.style.backgroundColor = 'lightgray'
            oval.style.borderStyle = 'none'
            oval.style.height = "100%";
            oval.style.width = "100%";
            oval.style.borderRadius = '10px'
            cell.appendChild(oval);
            eGui.appendChild(cell);
        }

        this.eGui = eGui;
    }

    getGui() {
        // Returns the same eGUI for each row
        return this.eGui;
    }
}

const gridOptions = {
    loadingCellRenderer: CustomLoadingCellRenderer,
    loadingCellRendererParams: {},
    rowModelType: "serverSide",
    serverSideDatasource: datasource,
}
```

[image]

For client side rendering, it doesn't really make sense to implement this using overlay Loading Template since rows doesn't generate individually, and you wouldn't know the expected number of the rows before the whole data is loaded. However, you could use the same custom renderer for `overlayLoadingTemplate` but generate the loadingCell to fill the whole grid.